# Custom FB pixel event not firing

Tags: javascript, facebook

I have the FB pixel helper browser plugin installed and I presume the FB pixel is installed properly as it is reporting pageviews just fine but this isn't working even though the console log is firing properly when I click the element on my page. Which happens to be a banner for an affiliate program. Please help.

```
 jQuery( "#affbanner" ).click(function(linkclick) {
    console.log("reportCustomEvent rdy");


    fbq('track', 'ViewContent', {
      content_name: 'Affiliate Site',
      content_category: 'main > sub',
      content_ids: ['1234'],
      content_type: 'product',
      value: 0.50,
      currency: 'USD'
     });

    console.log("onclick fired");   

    });
```

Comment: Presumably the navigation away from the page cancels any pending background requests …?

Comment: Could be but it works with other analytics type tags and I have the target page opening in a new tab with _blank.

Answer (score 0):

As you said page views are tracking and it is firing on console too in that case ehe possible reason for this could be -

The product id you are sending from the script should match with Facebook feed id of the product. Product id must match with the product feed id.

Moreover you can check this on Facebook Pixel helper chrome plugin.